# How to update queue/topic of Azure Service Bus via ARM?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I have a ARM (Azure Resource Manager) script that creates Service bus with topic and subscriber inside. It worked perfectly for some time, but I decided to enable session on topic and disable partitioning. Script was changed and during deployment it gives me:

```
Template deployment returned the following errors:
07:56:00 - Resource Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics 'ops-ServiceBus/default-topic' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "message": "SubCode=40000. Partitioning cannot be changed for Topic. . TrackingId:<some_guid>_M11CH3_M11CH3_G1, SystemTracker:ops-servicebus.servicebus.windows.net:default-topic, Timestamp:2019-03-28T04:55:56 CorrelationId: <some_guid>",
    "code": "BadRequest"
  }
}'
07:56:21 - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
```

Is it possible to perform update operation on Queue/Topic using ARM?

Answer (score 1):

We did configure queues\topics with arm templates, but according to the error - some parameters are immutable, so you'd have to recreate in this case.

Comment: That's correct. But what about topic? All data inside will be lost. What is proper procedure?

Comment: And second thing - how can I recreate topic? I'm using `Incremental` mode of `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`

Comment: you'd have to delete it manually or with script. deployment mode has nothing to do with that. nothing you can do about the data inside, back it up or process it before deleting it.